How to set Overprint Fill on text in pdf
I have that small chunk of code
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a new PDF document
    Doc theDoc = new Doc();

    // HTML content
    string htmlContent = @"
        <html>
        <body style='background-color: yellow;'>
            <p style='color: black;'>
                Black text should become yellow when Process Black is unchecked in Output Preview in Acrobat
            </p>
        </body>
        </html>";

    // Add the HTML to the document
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.MSHtml;
    theDoc.Rendering.ColorSpace = XRendering.ColorSpaceType.Cmyk;
    theDoc.Rendering.Overprint = true; 
    theDoc.AddImageHtml(htmlContent);

    foreach (IndirectObject io in theDoc.ObjectSoup)
    { 

        if (io is StreamObject)
        {
            StreamObject so = (StreamObject)theDoc.ObjectSoup[io.ID];
            so.Decompress();
            string content = so.GetText();

            // CMYK issue.
            // Pure yellow should stay pure yellow. Without this fix it makes ~97% yellow & ~5% Cyan
            string newContent = content.Replace("0 0 0 rg", "0 0 0 1 k")
                                        .Replace("0 0 0 RG", "0 0 0 1 K")
                                        .Replace("1 1 0 RG", "0 0 1 0 K")
                                        .Replace("1 1 0 rg", "0 0 1 0 k");

            // Only set new content if changed
            if (newContent != content)
                so.SetText(newContent);

            so.Compress();
        }
    } 

    // Save the document
    theDoc.Save("output.pdf");
    theDoc.Clear();
}

It generates PDF (in RGB) from HTML. Then I run a ghost script that converts it to PDF in CMYK. The problem is that when I open PDF in CMYK in Adobe Acrobat -> Print Production -> Output Preview -> Uncheck Process Black -> then the text becomes white but it should be overprinted by the yellow background
when I open that CMYK PDF in Adobe Acrobat and uncheck Process Black the text becomes white, but it should be yellow, it should be overprinted by the background.
Here is the Ghostscript command:
gswin64c -q -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output_cmyk.pdf -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dOverrideICC -sDefaultCMYKProfile=ISOnewspaper26v4.icc -dPDFX -f -dOPM=1 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dOverprint=/enable PDFX_def3.ps output.pdf

where PDFX_def3.ps is the following:
systemdict /ProcessColorModel known {
  systemdict /ProcessColorModel get dup /DeviceGray ne exch /DeviceCMYK ne and
} {
  true
} ifelse
{ (ERROR: ProcessColorModel must be /DeviceGray or DeviceCMYK.)=
  /ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
} if

% Define entries to the document Info dictionary :

% /ICCProfile (ISOnewspaper26v4.icc) def  % Customize or remove.

[ /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1a:2001) % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /Title (Classified Ad)          % Customize.
  /Trapped /False                  % Must be so (Ghostscript doesn't provide other).
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :

currentdict /ICCProfile known {
  [/_objdef {icc_PDFX} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} <</N systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceGray eq {1} {4} ifelse >> /PUT pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark
} if

% Define the output intent dictionary :

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFX} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFX} <<
  /Type /OutputIntent              % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /S /GTS_PDFX                     % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /OutputCondition (ISOnewspaper26v4) % Customize
  /Info (none)                     % Customize
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (ISOnewspaper26v4)      % Customize
  /RegistryName (http://www.color.org)   % Must be so (the standard requires).
  currentdict /ICCProfile known {
    /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFX}  % Must be so (see above).
  } if
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFX} ]>> /PUT pdfmark

These lines don't help
    theDoc.Rendering.ColorSpace = XRendering.ColorSpaceType.Cmyk;
    theDoc.Rendering.Overprint = true; 

I managed to set Fill Overpring on text using Adobe Illustrator, but I need to make it from the code
Edit:
Current output pdf in acrobat if the Black is unchecked 
Excpected behavior:

Edit 2
I checked what StreamObject content my output_cmyk.pdf has
q 0.24 0 0 0.24 0 0 cm
/R8 gs
q
0 3080 m
0 3300 l
2550 3300 l
2550 3080 l
h
W n
1 g
2553.19 3303.19 m
2553.19 3306.38 l
2556.38 3306.38 l
2556.38 3041.81 l
-6.375 3041.81 l
-6.375 3045 l
-3.1875 3045 l
2553.19 3045 l
f*
/R9 gs
0.09 0.075 0.075 0 k
2550 3300 m
2550 3303.19 l
2553.19 3303.19 l
2553.19 3045 l
-3.1875 3045 l
-3.1875 3048.19 l
0 3048.19 l
2550 3048.19 l
f*
0 0 1 0 k
0 3048.19 2550 251.813 re
f*
0 3048.19 2550 251.813 re
f*
0 0 0 1 k
q
4.16667 0 0 4.16667 0 0 cm BT
/R10 12.24 Tf
0.934144 0 0 1 7.65 769.05 Tm
0.21573 Tw
(Black text should become yellow when Process Black is unchecked in Output Preview in Acrobat )Tj
1 0 0 1 461.295 769.05 Tm
0 Tw
( )Tj
ET
Q
Q
/R9 gs
Q

and here is what it shows if I manually set Overprint Fill on text in AI
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 9.1-c002 79.dba3da3, 2023/12/13-05:06:49        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpGImg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/"
            xmlns:pdfxid="http://www.npes.org/pdfx/ns/id/"
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
            xmlns:pdfx="http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:xmpTPg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/t/pg/"
            xmlns:stDim="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/Dimensions#"
            xmlns:stFnt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/Font#"
            xmlns:xmpG="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/"
            xmlns:illustrator="http://ns.adobe.com/illustrator/1.0/">
         <xmp:CreateDate>2024-07-10T12:34:14+03:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2024-07-10T14:41:38+03:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2024-07-10T14:41:38+03:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmp:Thumbnails>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpGImg:width>256</xmpGImg:width>
                  <xmpGImg:height>24</xmpGImg:height>
                  <xmpGImg:format>JPEG</xmpGImg:format>
                  <xmpGImg:image> long string (looks like base64) </xmpGImg:image>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </xmp:Thumbnails>
         <pdfxid:GTS_PDFXVersion>PDF/X-1a:2001</pdfxid:GTS_PDFXVersion>
         <xmpMM:VersionID>1</xmpMM:VersionID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:c8e8491c-4375-4993-9c53-3a6ccd8ddc7e</xmpMM:InstanceID>
         <xmpMM:RenditionClass>proof:pdf</xmpMM:RenditionClass>
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:6e2384ad-b97e-4e33-bdeb-c05d97a7d538</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <pdfx:GTS_PDFXVersion>PDF/X-1a:2001</pdfx:GTS_PDFXVersion>
         <pdf:Producer>GPL Ghostscript 10.03.1</pdf:Producer>
         <pdf:Trapped>False</pdf:Trapped>
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Classified Ad</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <xmpTPg:NPages>1</xmpTPg:NPages>
         <xmpTPg:HasVisibleTransparency>False</xmpTPg:HasVisibleTransparency>
         <xmpTPg:HasVisibleOverprint>True</xmpTPg:HasVisibleOverprint>
         <xmpTPg:MaxPageSize rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <stDim:w>612.000000</stDim:w>
            <stDim:h>792.000000</stDim:h>
            <stDim:unit>Points</stDim:unit>
         </xmpTPg:MaxPageSize>
         <xmpTPg:Fonts>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stFnt:fontName>Times-Roman</stFnt:fontName>
                  <stFnt:fontFamily>Times Roman</stFnt:fontFamily>
                  <stFnt:fontFace>Roman</stFnt:fontFace>
                  <stFnt:fontType>Unknown</stFnt:fontType>
                  <stFnt:versionString>Version 2.106;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.70;makeotf.lib2.5.58329</stFnt:versionString>
                  <stFnt:composite>False</stFnt:composite>
                  <stFnt:fontFileName>MyriadPro-Regular.otf</stFnt:fontFileName>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </xmpTPg:Fonts>
         <xmpTPg:PlateNames>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>Cyan</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Magenta</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Yellow</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Black</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmpTPg:PlateNames>
         <xmpTPg:SwatchGroups>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpG:groupName>Default Swatch Group</xmpG:groupName>
                  <xmpG:groupType>0</xmpG:groupType>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmpTPg:SwatchGroups>
         <illustrator:CreatorSubTool>Adobe Illustrator</illustrator:CreatorSubTool>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                                                                                  
<?xpacket end="w"?>


Hey, I've updated the code with the appropriate comment , that color replacement was needed to correctly set the Yellow color in CMYK space (Without this fix it makes ~97% yellow & ~5% Cyan). Also, added the ghost script command and a postscript file. I was thinking of adding /OP true /op true to the newContent but it didn't help. Still if I open the file in Acrobat it says Page has Overprint: NO

Thanks for looking into it. I've added Current output and the expected output int the Edit section. I achieved the expected output by manually set Overprint Fill on text using Adobe Illustrator, and to be honest I doubt that it's possible to get the same output using ABCpdf. Let me know if you need any additional info

I think no, CMYK color space is required in the output file, moreover if I'm not wrong Overprinting is supported only in  CMYK

here is the link to the PS and ICC files https://filetransfer.io/data-package/dSwCXkgX#link. Also, you mentioned my working output, if I understand you correctly 'working output' means the output PDF file that is generated by the code and Ghostscript command, so you can find it through the link above

I've added the contents of the streams in Edit 2 sections, maybe it helps

okay, I'll update the ICC profile, also I was thinking of adding something like this at the end of PDFX_def3.ps file
% Enable overprint mode and overprint fill
[/Overprint true /OP true /OPM 1 /PDF pdfmark
                              % Set text to overprint

[/OCProperties <<
/OCGs [ <<
/Type /OCG
/Name (Overprint)
/Usage <<
/View [/ON]
/Print << /PrintState /ON >>
/Export << /ExportState /ON >>
>>


]
/PUT pdfmark



Didn't know that, I'll try with PDF/X-3 and let you know what I get

looks like nothing has changed, I ended up that it's the responsibility of the PostScript and GS to set the overprint, so I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78733932/how-to-add-overprint-fill-on-text-in-postscript-file. I've managed to set overprint only on the whole page, but I don't know how to apply it to the text. I'd really appreciate if you could look into it
