How to add Overprint Fill on text in PostScript file
I have a ghost command that gets PGB PDF as input and generates CMYK PDF. What I need to achive is to make the text overprinted, so when I open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat -> Use print production -> Output Preview and uncheck Process Black then the text should disappear (should be overprinted by the background)
Here is the Ghostscript command:
gswin64c -q -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output_cmyk.pdf -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dOverrideICC -sDefaultCMYKProfile=TIC220_WANIFRA_NP26.icc -dOPM=1 -dOverprint=/enable -dCompatibilityLevel=1.6 -f PDFX_def3.ps output.pdf

Where PDFX_def3.ps is:
systemdict /ProcessColorModel known {
  systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceCMYK ne
} {
  true
} ifelse
{ (ERROR: ProcessColorModel must be /DeviceCMYK.)=
  /ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
} if

% Define entries to the document Info dictionary :
 

[ /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-4) % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /Title (Classified Ad)          % Customize.
  /Trapped /False                  % Must be so (Ghostscript doesn't provide other).
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :

currentdict /ICCProfile known {
  [/_objdef {icc_PDFX} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} <</N 4 >> /PUT pdfmark
  [{icc_PDFX} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark
} if

% Define the output intent dictionary :

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFX} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFX} <<
  /Type /OutputIntent              % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /S /GTS_PDFX                     % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /OutputCondition (TIC220_WANIFRA_NP26) % Customize
  /Info (none)                     % Customize
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (TIC220_WANIFRA_NP26)      % Customize
  /RegistryName (http://www.color.org)   % Must be so (the standard requires).
  currentdict /ICCProfile known {
    /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFX}  % Must be so (see above).
  } if
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFX} ]>> /PUT pdfmark

% Ensure overprint settings for all pages
/BeginPage {
  % Enable overprint for fills and strokes
  true setoverprint
} bind def
 

% Ensure BeginPage is called for each page
<< /BeginPage {BeginPage} >> setpagedevice

The problem is that looks like these lines
% Ensure overprint settings for all pages
/BeginPage {
  % Enable overprint for fills and strokes
  true setoverprint
} bind def
 

% Ensure BeginPage is called for each page
<< /BeginPage {BeginPage} >> setpagedevice

set the overprint on the whole page, but I need to apply it specificaly on text.
Here is the link where you can find my initial pdf file(output.pdf), genereated pdf file (output_cmyk.pdf), ICC profile and PS file
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/jtuCS4KS#link
Edit 1:
Tried that approach in PS file
% Ensure overprint settings for all pages
/BeginPage {
  true setoverprint
} bind def

% Ensure BeginPage is called for each page
<< /BeginPage {BeginPage} >> setpagedevice

% Apply overprint specifically to Black (100% K)
/setOP {  
  gsave
  currentcmykcolor
  % Store the CMYK values on the stack
  /K exch def
  /Y exch def
  /M exch def
  /C exch def

  K 1 eq
  C 0 eq
  M 0 eq
  Y 0 eq
  exch and                           
  exch and                           
  exch and  
  {              
    true setoverprint % Set overprint if color is 100% black
  } {              
    false setoverprint % Unset overprint otherwise
  } ifelse
    grestore
} bind def

/show { setOP } bind def 
setOP

but still, the Black text didn't get Overprint Fill

WHY are you swapping ICC - this is what I got from the legacy, but I suppose it's needed to map RGB to GMYK color (I may be wrong)
Output requirements -> the CMYK PDF file should be generated, with the Overprint Fill on text, so we won't have white places near to letters when printing

so, what you're saying is that it makes more sense to let the publishers manually apply Overprint configuration using tools like Acrobat Illustrator etc. rather than trying to implement a codewise approach of applying Overprint on text?

I checked your file in Acrobat, it says that the page has overprint but if I uncheck Proccess Black -> the text is white, but should be overprinted by the yellow background.
I also was thinking of applying Overprint Fill to everything that is in black color (you can see it in Edit 1 section). But looks like it still doesn't give me overrinted text. I'm pretty sure that something is wrong in my PS, but I can't figure out what exactly since the PS docs aren't really rich. Could you please advise? And from your experience, is it even possible to get desired output using PS?
